# Options to setup IMAP server on your PC

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap, hmail-server

Is there any option to install IMAP server locally ?
I tried hMailServer but it's setup correctly and not starting.

Do you see any alternate option.

**Problem trying to solve :**
Want to read inbox using javax mail for the same reason need fake IMAP server so I could add any email to it and try to read after that.

Thank you

Comment: All of the IMAP servers can be set up locally. They are, somewhere, that's how they're used. And in particular, *all* of the server developers do that. I personally am blessedly unaware of how to set up things on that "windows" OS, though.

Comment: Try Apache James.